# Windows 7: What PATH to set to when using Conda

Tags: python-3.x, windows-7, path, conda

I've got anaconda installed and was able to create a Python 3.3 environment. I can switch to it and `conda info -e` shows that I've switched.

However, I'm confused about what to set my PATH variable to. If I hard code it to the exact env then it works, but I thought that the purpose of conda was to be able to switch easily, as well as update and maintain various environments separately.

Perhaps I misunderstood and there's no way around setting my PATH everytime...

Comment: I don't think there is an automagically way to change paths from the conda manager. I'll have to write a script...I'm a BASH guy but I suppose some DOS never hurt.

Comment: How are you switching to it?

Answer (score 0):

In the Windows cmd shell, use the `activate` and `deactivate` commands to change the PATH automatically. For instance, if your environment is called `python3`, run `python3` to "activate" (i.e., add to the `PATH`) the `python3` environment. Use `deactivate` to remove it.

Comment: Thanks, I did try that. It seems like I still have to set the path in DOS with

Comment: I did use activate, but that appears to only change the working path of Conda, and not the system path. Perhaps I phrased my question poorly.

Comment: Right, activate only changes the PATH for that shell, not the global PATH. I don't know if there are any tools that change the global PATH, other than changing it manually.